# Why isn't the submit button working here?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

https://codepen.io/475513a/pen/bobWbw

Above's a link to codepen for easy viewing.

I've added two buttons - one inside the form, and one outside. Both buttons share same jQuery event - however, the button inside the form does nothing and refreshes the page - despite me telling it to e.preventDefault.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make button inside the form do the same thing as the one outside?

HTML

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="newValue">Add</button>  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="foodName">Food</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foodName" placeholder="Strawberries">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="proteinValue">Protein</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="proteinValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fatValue">Fat</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="fatValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="carbValue">Carbs</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="carbValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="newValue">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Units</th>
          <th>Protein</th>
          <th>Fat</th>
          <th>Carbs</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food A</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food B</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food C</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>34</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
  $("#newValue").on("click", function(e){
    var newFoodName = $("#foodName").val();
    var newProteinValue = $("#proteinValue").val();
    var newFatValue = $("#fatValue").val();
    var newCarbValue = $("#carbValue").val();

    var $newThFoodName = $("<th>", {
      text: newFoodName
    });
    var $newThUnits = $("<th>", {
      text: "100g"
    });
    var $newTrProteinValue = $("<td>", {
      text: newProteinValue
    });
    var $newTrFatValue = $("<td>", {
      text: newFatValue
    });
    var $newTrCarbValue = $("<td>", {
      text: newCarbValue
    });
   var $newTr = $("<tr>");

    $newTr.append( $newThFoodName ).append( $newThUnits ).append( $newTrProteinValue ).append( $newTrFatValue ).append( $newTrCarbValue );

    $("tbody").append($newTr);
    e.preventDefault;

  });

});
```

CSS

```
@import "lesshat";

.form-inline .form-control {
    margin: 0rem 1rem;
}

#proteinValue, #fatValue, #carbValue {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique.  You cannot have two elements with the same id (`newValue` in your case).

Comment: After I removed the first `newValue` (outside), the button element inside the form still doesn't work (page keeps refreshing...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues. Firstly you have given both buttons the same `id`, hence the latter one is ignored in JS.

Secondly, you've prevented the `click` event of the button. To stop the request being made from the form submission you would be better hooking to the `submit` event of the form instead.

Finally, note that DOM operations are very, very slow (relatively speaking), so it's much better practice to build the HTML as a single string and only call `append()` once. Try this:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addRow();
});

$("#newValue").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  addRow();
});

function addRow() {
  var newFoodName = $("#foodName").val();
  var newProteinValue = $("#proteinValue").val();
  var newFatValue = $("#fatValue").val();
  var newCarbValue = $("#carbValue").val();
  
  $("tbody").append('<tr><th>' + newFoodName + '</th><th>100g</th><th>' + newProteinValue + '</th><th>' + newFatValue + '</th><th>' + newCarbValue + '</th></tr>');
}
```

```css
.form-inline .form-control {
  margin: 0rem 1rem;
}

#proteinValue,
#fatValue,
#carbValue {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="newValue">Add</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="foodName">Food</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foodName" placeholder="Strawberries">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="proteinValue">Protein</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="proteinValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fatValue">Fat</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="fatValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="carbValue">Carbs</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="carbValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Units</th>
          <th>Protein</th>
          <th>Fat</th>
          <th>Carbs</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food A</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food B</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food C</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>34</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="containerz"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you also for the advice on append.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the code below. Here I use class named as 'newValue' to initialize click event because the `Id` is supposed to be unique.
Then I have change the button type as button. So that the form will not fire the submit event and the form won't reload.

```js
$(function(){
 

  $(".newValue").on("click", function(e){
    var newFoodName = $("#foodName").val();
    var newProteinValue = $("#proteinValue").val();
    var newFatValue = $("#fatValue").val();
    var newCarbValue = $("#carbValue").val();
    
    var $newThFoodName = $("<th>", {
      text: newFoodName
    });
    var $newThUnits = $("<th>", {
      text: "100g"
    });
    var $newTrProteinValue = $("<td>", {
      text: newProteinValue
    });
    var $newTrFatValue = $("<td>", {
      text: newFatValue
    });
    var $newTrCarbValue = $("<td>", {
      text: newCarbValue
    });
   var $newTr = $("<tr>");
    
    $newTr.append( $newThFoodName ).append( $newThUnits ).append( $newTrProteinValue ).append( $newTrFatValue ).append( $newTrCarbValue );
    
    $("tbody").append($newTr);
    e.preventDefault;
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
@import "lesshat";

.form-inline .form-control {
    margin: 0rem 1rem;
}

#proteinValue, #fatValue, #carbValue {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="newValue btn btn-default" id="newValue">Add</button>  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="foodName">Food</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foodName" placeholder="Strawberries">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="proteinValue">Protein</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="proteinValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fatValue">Fat</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="fatValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="carbValue">Carbs</label>
          <input type="number" class="dgt form-control " id="carbValue" placeholder="26">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="newValue btn btn-default" id="newValue">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Units</th>
          <th>Protein</th>
          <th>Fat</th>
          <th>Carbs</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food A</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food B</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Food C</th>
          <td>100 grams</td>
          <td>123</td>
          <td>54</td>
          <td>34</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="containerz"></div>
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?